# How to hide div content but leave some content in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a div like this:

```
<div class="someDiv">
<span>This content should remain</span>
 The rest of this content needs to be hidden (Faded out)
</div>
```

I can't change the actual structure of the HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `visibility` CSS attribute:

```
$('.someDiv').css('visibility','hidden')
    .find('span').css('visibility','visible');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/WtMea/

I don't think it's possible to fade the outer `div` without also fading everything inside of it, but  `visibility` can be overridden.

Comment: This won't work. If the `.someDiv` is hidden, it won't matter if the `span` is visible.

Comment: @RightSaidFred Who said `.someDiv` was hidden? He just wanted to hide the rest of the content, which this does (albeit without fading).

Comment: Well, `$('.someDiv').css('visibility','hidden')`, but looks like you're right. Seems that the visibility of the span overrides that of the `.someDiv`. +1

Comment: It works in all the browsers I tested, looks like it might be my only option.  I can't get fade effects to work but I guess those aren't really necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
$('.someDiv').append('<span id="fade"></span').find('#fade').html($('.someDiv').contents().filter(function(){ return this.nodeType == 3; })).fadeOut(1000);
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/gdNue/1/

Comment: That almost works perfectly, the JQuery get's confused where there is multiple elements inside of the div though It doesn't quite hide everything in that scenario.  Even an extra p tag doesn't get hidden.

Comment: This is the probably the best solution for your posted code as it selects the textnode and then fades it out. However it will of course only select direct descendent textnodes and not children elements, as that was pretty much your question, if you wan't to remove other elements as well you will have to add those to your code, that would be the easy part. The other answer will of course work because it hides everything and then shows the span, but the right way is usually to select the actual elements you wish to target, and not to target everything and then undo it on certain elements.

Comment: the problem is the internal elements could contain an inumerable amount of inner contents and I can't control what they are, so I need a way to hide everything.